# Path to sdcard's files

Tags: android, hyperlink, path, storage

I want to make a hyperlink app so that whenever I click on the text with link, the browser will display the webpage or the file manager will open the specific files in sdcard etc. I tried to use html method:

```
<a href="...">Text</a>
```

I successfully did with web URL (in ... field I just insert a link of http://google.com for example). However, I still get trouble with access local storage's files.
I tries several formats of sdcard's directory such as `file://sdcard`, `file://mnt/sdcard`, `/sdcard/` however none of them works.
Which kind of path should I use here?

Comment: Do you want to open File Manager from HTML hyperlink....?

Comment: You should not hard code paths. Better use getExternalStorageDirectory and getExternalFilesDir(s) to find those paths.

Comment: @greenapps The problem is that in my app, the link is the input that user needs to type